# Fill table range with textbox1.value

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim tl As Integer

t1 = 33

'**************

Dim tbl1 As Table
Dim rng As Range

Set doc = ActiveDocument    
Set tbl1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(t1)
Set rng = doc.Range(Start:=tbl1.Cell(2, 5).Range.Start, _
     End:=tbl1.Cell(100, 5).Range.End)

rng.Text = TextBox1.Text
```

When I press the button, this code does not work properly, I can fill only `Start:=tbl1.Cell(2, 5)`.... This fills only 1 cell

But `End:=tbl1.Cell(100, 5).Range.End)` doesn't work. It does not fill all the rows.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You want to write the same text content to all the cells (except the first) in column 5 of the table? What you're trying to do won't work, you need to write to each cell individually.

Comment: Yes, I was tried to do range and this work if I do copy/past. Example: if I say copy table (1) (1,1) value to a range that I set (start-end) all work, but the same thing doesn't work textbox.... hmmm i will try to check macropod answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all of the cells concerned. For example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim tl As Long, r As Long
t1 = 33
With ActiveDocument.Tables(t1)
  For r = 2 To 100
    .Cell(r, 5).Range.Text = TextBox1.Text
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: macropod , Thanks working for me, but can you explain to me why I need a loop? why doesn't range set work (start,end)?

Comment: Simply setting a range only tells you where you want to insert something - it says nothing about how many instances you might want to insert. If you set the range to point to 5 consecutive paragraphs, for example, you'd end up with just one paragraph containing one instance of your output; it's only because you're outputting to a table that the 99 output cells aren't reduced to one...

Comment: Yes but if i set this :                                                             
                tbl1.Cell(1, 1).Range.Copy
                                                                                                        Set rng = doc.Range(Start:=tbl2.Cell(2, 5).Range.Start, _
    End:=tbl2.Cell(100, 5).Range.End)
    rng.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatOriginalFormatting).   all work

Comment: In other words if i copy value from other table cell all work, hmmmm anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same technique that you discovered for copy one cell to multiple cells, that should also work. It's a bit tricky, though, and you don't give us enough information to reproduce the TextBox, so you may need to tweak the following.

I put the ActiveX text box on the document surface and pick it up using the `InlineShapes` collection. If you're using a UserForm you'll need to change that part.

It's not possible to assign a `Column` in Word to a `Range` object. A `Range` must be a contiguous flow of text. In Word, the contiguous flow is horizontal, then vertical - so `Rows` can be assigned to a `Range`, but not a column. (And that is why the other Answer loops the cells in the column, which is comparatively slow.)

It is possible, however, to *select* a column and work with the `Selection`. So the code below copies the content of the text box to the clipboard, then selects the entire column and pastes to the `Selection`.

```
Sub CopyToMultipleCells()
    Dim tl As Integer
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim tb As MSForms.TextBox

    tl = 1

    '**************

    Dim tbl1 As Table
    Dim rng As Range

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    'Change if on a UserForm
    Set tb = doc.InlineShapes(1).OleFormat.Object
    'Select the text box content, then copy it
    tb.SelStart = 0
    tb.SelLength = tb.TextLength
    tb.Copy

    Set tbl1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(tl)
    tbl1.Columns(5).Select
    Selection.Paste        
End Sub
```